# Uploaded file is unable to read after downloading in PHP

Tags: php

I wrote php script to upload file from admin panel and to download for user. 
Uploading was done successfully but after downloading the file, it is unable to read. if it is a image file or pdf file. The uploaded files are copied to xamp/htdocs/myproject/admin/documents.  and the path is stored to mysql database. When i tried to download it the file size is different for uploaded file and downloaded file and it is unable to read.

The uploading script

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
 $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
 $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

if ($name) {
  $location = "documents/$name";
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
  $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts (name,path) VALUES ('$location')");
}
```

Comment: after uploading the file and storing Path into DB, are you getting right file extension ? If yes then you make client side to download the file? How you are allowing user to download those file. Because you need to have correct headers

Comment: for one thing, you have 2 columns but only 1 value `(name,path) VALUES ('$location')`

Comment: this question is far too unclear

Comment: Incorrectly stored information to the database so its unlikely you are actually sending a file to the user

Comment: Thanks everybody for helping me. {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for helping me. i made changes for my script yesterday and it is working but the problem is that when i tried to add it to my project it is not working.

my uploads script(it is writen in myproject/admin/application.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

if ($name) {
  $location = "documents/$name";
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
  $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts (name,path) VALUES ('$location')");   
}
```

download.php (Written in myproject/download.php)

```
<?php
 include('includes/connect.php');
  if (isset($_GET['dow']))  {
     $path = $_GET['dow'];
      $res = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE path = '$path'");

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($path) . "\";");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download
exit;
   }


 ?>
```

The linking script to download.php b (written in myproject/viewprofile.php)

```
<?php
  include('includes/connect.php');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);






    $path   = $row['post_path'];

     echo "<a href='download.php?dow=$path' class='btn btn-dark btn-theme-colored btn-flat mr-5' style='width:100%; margin-top:5px;'> DOWNLOAD RESUME </a> <br>";

 ?>
```